# What would be common superclass from these two (I need to extract a couple of common methods)?

Tags: java, generics, gwt, gxt

I need to refactor some code but even though the second class `extends` the first one, I can't seem to find the common class to use as a method argument:

```
public class TreeStore<M extends ModelData> extends com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.TreeStore<M> { }
```

and

```
public class CustomTreeStore<M extends ClientBaseBean> extends TreeStore<M> { }
```

I tried:

```
exampleMethod(TreeStore<M> store, ....)
```

Method definition:

```
public static <M extends ModelData> void exampleMethod(TreeStore<M> store, M parent, List<M> children, ...) { }
```

As far as `ModelData` is concerned, it is an interface, from which a pretty complex hierarchy stems.

When calling the above method in both classes, I simply pass `this` - it works for the first one but the IDE complains about the second one.

Shouldn't it be working in second case as well, since that class `extends` the first one? I guess it has something to do with the `M extends ClientBaseBean` generic parameter? If so, how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: What is the definition of M in `exampleMethod(TreeStore<M>)`? Perhaps paste the full code, or at least (a lot) more than what you have. The two places you can define generics is in your class def (`class Foo<M> { ... }`), and a method def (`public <T> T foo(T bar)`).

Comment: @rzwitserloot I updated the question

Comment: Your question still cannot be answered - not enough detail. Include the _exact_ call that is failing, including the compiler error message. For example, your method def uses M in many places, perhaps the problem isn't directly the CustomTreeStore signature, but the stuff you're passing for the 'parent' and 'children' fields. Those can't just be typed 'ModelData', for example.